# How to make GridLayout responsive?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a form that I want to be responsive with regard to the width of the window in the following way:

- when the width of the window is less than a certain `maximumWidth`, say `1000px`, the form should take up the whole available width.
- when the window is made wider than the `maximumWidth`, the form should be centered horizontlly with a fixed width of say `900px`.

Here is my code:

*main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800 // 1100
    title: "Stack"

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        GridLayout {
            columns: 2

            CVerticalLabel {
                text: "Miscellaneous"
                background: "blue"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }

            GridLayout {
                columns: 2

                Text {
                    text: "Company Name"
                    color: "red"
                    font.bold: true
                    font.pointSize: 16
                }

                TextField  {
                    objectName: "company_name"
                    font.bold: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    implicitWidth: 1000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*CVerticalLabel.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Item {
    id: control
    property string text
    property color color: "red"
    property color background: "blue"
    property real bgOpacity: 0.6

    width: 15 * 1.6

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: control
        color: control.background
        opacity: control.bgOpacity
    }

    Text {
        color: control.color
        text: control.text
        font.bold: true
        font.pointSize: 10
        width: control.height
        height: control.width
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        rotation: 90
        y: -height
        transformOrigin: Item.BottomLeft
    }
}
```

The code produces the following result:

[image: Window with a fixed-width, left-aligned form]

The problem is, that the form is aligned to the left and its size is always fixed, i.e. it does not take into account the different window widths. So the second column is not stretched to fill the rest of the available width.

How to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

In order to make the `GridLayout` centered on the page with a maximum width of `900px` when the window width exceeds `1000px` I would suggest you the following solution:

1. Add a `Page` as a parent of your `ScrollView`:

   ```
   Page {
       id: page
       anchors.fill: parent

       ScrollView {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make the left anchor margin of the `GridLayout` dynamic by taking into account the width of the bounding rectangle of its children, as well as the width of the `Page`:

   ```
   anchors.leftMargin: (page.width - childrenRect.width)/2
   ```

**Note:** This solution is similar to the way [`Flow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html) is being centered, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47168527/5366641).

## Example

Here is an example I have created for you of how your code could be changed in order to implement the proposed solution:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 1400

    Page {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        property int responsiveWidth: 1000
        property int maximumWidth: 900

        ScrollView {
            anchors.fill: parent

            GridLayout {
                columns: 2

                width: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? page.maximumWidth : page.width
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: (page.width - childrenRect.width)/2

                CVerticalLabel {
                    text: "Miscellaneous"
                    background: "blue"
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                }

                GridLayout {
                    columns: 2

                    CTextLabel {
                        text: "Company Name"
                        color: "red"
                    }

                    PanelTextField  {
                        objectName: "company_name"
                        font.bold: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Result

The provided example produces the following results:

- for window width `@800px`

[image: Window with a full-width form]

- for window width `@1100px`

[image: Window with a 900px-wide form]

Comment: Hello, this seems good. Just a question where can i learn how to do responsive layouts like this with qml? I find it very hard to find good information.

Comment: @Nmaster88, This is a question I am not able to answer. I personally have used only the official QML documentation and examples. The rest is to analyze the task and to know how to use the tools to solve it.

Comment: u find the documentation good? coming from the web i find this really hard

Comment: @Nmaster88, :) for me it is the opposite. I find it overcomplicated to make layouts with plain CSS. Of course, nowadays we have something like `grid`, but still...

Comment: yes with html we need css files and even js. but its really fast to make changes and see how they affect the layout, i immediately see them on the browser, while on QT for each change i need to run the app again. Is there a faster way to see changes on the app? because the design tab is unreliable.